# How to create a scheduled task that blocks access to the Internet but not to the local network?

Tags: networking, scheduled-tasks, netsh

I need your help. I should to create a scheduled task that blocks access to the Internet but I must have access to the local network. Also this task should work on weekdays from 8:00am to 5:00pm.

Answer (score 0):

Don't setup a Standard Gateway. It's probably easier to limit access on the responsible router if it is a SOHO environment.

The script would have to add or remove the standard gateway. Depending on your setup you might need to setup additional routes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking this question in regards to Windows client systems:

First of all you need to build the correct windows-firewall rules (e.g. block any udp/tcp traffic, on any port).

After that you can fit all these firewall settings into a .bat-script to execute them.

this .bat-script is what you want to execute on a regular basis to make sure the client system blocks outbound traffic.

also make sure unpriviledged users cant change or set new firewall-rules